# How to use pipe in property binding?

Tags: angular

I have the following code

```
perfectResultDownwards = 20;
```

```
 <span title="Theoretically cheapest price is € {{ perfectResultDownwards }}">10 %</span>
```

so when i hover on the span then there is tooltop on that element that is showing 20.

But how can i apply on property binding some pipe

when i try

```
 <span title="Theoretically cheapest price is € {{ perfectResultDownwards | myCustomPipe }}">10 %</span>
```

i get error

How can i do this ?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written and shown so far seem correct.
Can you show the code behind your custom pipe?
Is it referenced in your module?
Have you checked the console for errors?

**You can do a quick test to be sure pipes work fine in your scenario**
Change your code as follows:

```
<span title="Theoretically cheapest price is € {{ perfectResultDownwards | uppercase }}">10 %</span>

perfectResultDownwards = 'Twenty';
```

Test and it'll work fine. So I suspect the implementation of the custom pipe needs checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the brackets to inject variable into the tag:

```
  <span [title]="'Theoretically cheapest price is €' + perfectResultDownwards | currency">10 %</span>
```